# Using git with non romanised languages?

Tags: git

Git is such a great tool, but Im discovering it appears to have been designed primarily (or only) for english speakers. Does anyone know how to get git to play nicely with other languages, it is almost non usable. Best way to explain the problem is to show some git output:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   "103\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2546\346\230\237\346\234\237 5\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2545\346\230\237\346\234\237 1\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2545\346\230\237\346\234\237 2\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2545\346\230\237\346\234\237 3\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2545\346\230\237\346\234\237 4\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2545\346\230\237\346\234\237 5\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "201\350\254\233\347\276\251 \347\254\2546\346\230\237\346\234\237 1\351\240\201.txt"
#   new file:   "PAC2 \347\254\254\345\233\233\350\252\262.sh"
#   new file:   "PAC2 \347\254\254\345\233\233\350\252\262.sh"
#   new file:   "PAC2 \347\254\254\345\233\233\350\252\262.sh"
#   new file:   "\344\270\255\346\226\207\350\252\236\346\263\225.txt"
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "\344\270\255\346\226\207\350\252\236\346\263\225.txt.bak"
```

Hmm, I wonder what the heck files are about to be committed?!?!

Comment: This seems to be by design. http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/122860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting

```
git config core.quotepath false
```

could help.

[Source](http://blog.fealdia.org/2010/01/16/git-status-utf-8-umlaut-tip/)